# Load the data to table and remove the old rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i'm using a bootstrap table and need to load new data each time I click on a button, I don't want to keep old data.
I could load data using this below code but old data still there, I tried "load" instead of append like this `$('#matable tbody').load(rows);` it doesn't work

```js
var rows = $("<tr><td style=\"display:none;\">1</td><td>E</td><td>E</td><td>E</td></tr>");
$("#Mybutton").click(function() 
  $('#matable tbody').append(rows);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="matable" class="table table-striped table-bordered first">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Flux name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Flux name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) There's a syntax error in your code. Check the console to find the error and fix it. 2) There is no `tbody` element in your HTML...

Comment: Use `.html(rows)` instead of `.append(rows)`

Comment: Thank you :D , it works fine with .html(rows), but i noticed that the content of the seconde page of my table is not deleted and nothing happen if i click again on the button, any idea please ?